# Can't unload modules from the environment

Tags: python

I want to remove several redundant pre-production modules. So I try this but it doesn't work:

```py
for module in sys.modules:
    if 'outlook_preprod' in module:
        del module
```

because then I can still see them:

```py
for module in sys.modules:
    if 'outlook_preprod' in module:
        print(module)

outlook_preprod_v1
outlook_preprod_v2
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I guess, you mean `del sys.modules[module]` ?

Comment: If you've already imported a module, and have a name referring to it, then the module will keep existing for as long as that name refers to it.  Nothing you can possibly do via `sys.modules` will change that fact.